# How to send Hexa decimal value Through TCP?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tcp, network-programming

```
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect("10.54.3.123", 43454);
        Stream stream = client.GetStream();

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

        writer.WriteLine("Testing...");

        writer.Close();

        client.Close();
```

Here is my code.Testing is my string and Hexadecimal value are 0x11.
Instead of "("Testing...");",I have to  send Hexadecimal value like 0x11.

Comment: You are confusing a few concepts: text data, binary data and hexadecimal notation. You should probably find out what each of those mean and how they differ.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send them as a string

```
int value1 = 17;
writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:x}", value1));
```

an reformat it on the server side.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what exactly you want to do? But...

```
byte[] hexValues = { 0x11, 0x11, 0x11 };
writer.WriteLine(hexValues);
```

Maybe this will help  you.